# Can I disable "Upgrade debugger from GDB to LLDB" warning in XCode 4.3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, lldb

I don't want to beta-test the LLDB debugger for Apple. How can I make XCode stop nagging me to upgrade the debugger? Seeing that warning exclamation point every time I build is rather irritating.

Comment: It may be annoying, but at least it allows you to build and run.  Besides, what's so bad about the latest LLDB that you don't want to use it?

Comment: @CodaFi: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707883/gdb-vs-lldb-debuggers. Also, when I tried LLDB, it would crash upon hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: You mean Xcode would crash, or the app?

Comment: Oh, I see.  As far as I know this is a "bug" in Xcode, and there arent any linker flags to fix it!

Comment: I'd love to love LLDB. I've tried to love it. I never thought a debugger could get more lost than gdb, but LLDB has topped it. When you throw C++ code at it, LLDB just seems to cry. gdb gets confused in ObjC++, but at least it can handle C++ pretty well. Even in the ObjC code, LLDB often tells me that an object has no description. I'm totally with Emile here. I hate gdb, and I want to love LLDB. Some day I'm sure that will be true, but not today.

Comment: And what's bugging me silly is that even though I accept Xcode's warning and allow it to change to LLDB, when I restart Xcode and re-open my project, the warning is STILL THERE. I've been working for weeks without being able to get rid of this annoying warning no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CodaFi's comment above, there's currently no way to disable that warning.