# NSMutableArray remove Object is cloning another object in the Array

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have an strange error after removing an object in a NSMutableArray.

[image: Before deleting an object]

If i remove an object with

```
[Array removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

the array changed to this:

[image]

why are there now 2 ContactViewControllers??

Comment: +1 Excellent question.  Did you notice that the original `SolutionViewController` at index 6 has gone missing too?

Comment: can you show more of the code?

Comment: This has nothing directly to do with our question, but do yourself a favor and don't use uppercase object/variable names. In Objective-C, only classes, interfaces and the like should have uppercase names.

Comment: it is not cloning by the way. It is the same pointer.

Comment: how are you able to expand an array in the debug mode (like your screen shots)? i can't seem to do it..

Comment: @DavidBenAri Via breakpoint.

Comment: Obviously via breakpoint. i still don't see. i'll stop spamming this post and ask a Question..

Comment: @DavidBenAri [Xcode 4.6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW216)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lldb lies sometimes. It gets confused and will display the incorrect information. Try doing

```
po Array
```

you should see the correct array contents then.

Comment: This is scary... I thought Apple would've fixed [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963268/float-variables-assigned-value-from-line-above/10963683#10963683) by now

Comment: Yes it's quite stupid. lldb will often fail to showing anything up the stack, and sometimes confuses one variable with another.