# Retrieval of NSArray from NSUserDefaults returns empty array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I am experiencing strange behaviour with `NSUserDefaults`. I am initially storing an array to the user defaults in my **AppDelegate.m**:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *weekdayIDs = [defaults objectForKey:@"weekdayIDs"];

if (weekdayIDs == nil) {
weekdayIDs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"su", @"mo", @"tu", @"we", @"th", @"fr", @"sa", nil];
[defaults setObject:weekdayIDs forKey:@"weekdayIDs"];
}

[defaults synchronize];
```

Now in a different view controller **ContentViewController.m**, I want to retrieve the array:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *weekdayIDs = [defaults objectForKey:@"weekdayIDs"];
```

But I just get an array without objects, although its `count == 7`. I also used `arrayForKey:` but with the same result. I added a screenshot from my breakpoint.

[image]

I am regularly using `NSUserDefaults`, but currently I am bit stuck on this. It's probably a stupid mistake, anyone care to help?

Thank you so much!

-- Update:

I also figured it might be a problem with the init of the NSArray in the first place, but even replacing its objects with manually created `NSString *dwid_su = [NSString stringWithString:@"su"];` didn't work.

Comment: Hi Julian. Did you try to `NSLog` your array? Also what do you get if you do a `po weekdayIDs` in your debugger console?

Comment: I thought so, if you're interested on why you had the problem in the first place, here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963268/float-variables-assigned-value-from-line-above/10963683#10963683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly.

Just, print the description of you array and you will see what you want.

Right click on `weekdayIDs` variable and select *Print Description of weekdayIDs*

or use through lldb debugger console `po weekdayIDs`

or `NSLog(@"%@", weekdayIDs);`

Here the results.

[image]

Comment: You are right, thanks so much. I thought the array was the problem and was led on the wrong track, as the error was somewhere else. But now I got it. PS: It's already 11 pm in Germany. :-S

Comment: @Julian do the sync only when the array is nil. This if you use only that snippet of code you posted otherwise leave as is. But I suppose you write other defaults...

Comment: Exactly. There are some defaults I have to initialize.