# C++: Strange behavior: Return value changes on the return statement

Tags: c++, memory-management, return, undefined-behavior

I'm facing a *very very* strange behavior my application.

I'm going to describe my situation and then explain what is going wrong.

### Situation

I have a method with a signature like this:

```
const StructureDef *getStructure(const std::string &theme, int index);
```

And I call it in this piece of code:

```
const StructureDef *sDef = 0;
do 
{
    sDef = ss->getStructure(theme, rand() % ss->availableStructureCount());
} while (!sDef);
```

I'm using this do-while structure, because the return value of the `getStructure` method might be `NULL`, depending on the combination of `theme` and `index`. So basically, what it does is asking random structures until we get a valid one. (If you want to know the detail, take a look at the screenshots.)

The method iterates over a `std::vector<StructureDef>` using it's `::iterator`. And for each StructureDef, it checks if the structure belongs to that theme. If so, post-increase the counter and check if it is equal to the requested index. Like this:

```
// inside the loop
if (i++ == index)
```

When this if succeeds, the current `StructureDef *` is returned:

```
return sDef;
```

### What is going wrong

I'm using XCode 4.4 it's debugger to see step by step what is going on, which is basically gdb.

The method I explained first, find a `StructureDef *` that matches my needs. So it returns that pointer. Here is a screenshot of the moment just before it is going to return in the debugger:

[image: Return point in the debugger]

<sup>(The line after the for-loop is simply `return 0;`</sup>)

Here the pointer `sDef *` points to `0x1d563270`, which is where the correct instance of the `StructureDef` is located.

Next screenshot is what we get in the piece of code where I called that method:

[image: Caller gets wrong address]

As you can see, the pointer `sDef *`, which got the return value of the method, now points to `0x2fe03804`. This is not what the method returned at all! I'm thinking that this is pointer points to somewhere on the stack, instead of the heap. (It should be the heap since the std::vector class stores its objects on the heap, right?).

I can't use Valgrind yet, since I'm on Mac OS X 10.8, which isn't supported by Valgrind.

I'm totally surprised by this behavior. I can't see why this is happening... Can it be that my compiler is broken, or is it doing some strange *"optimization"*?

Thanks in advance!
Martijn

---

To clarify DeadMG's comment:

I'm using different themes:

```
iron
wood
ice
```

etc...

My identifiers look like this:

```
iron__downside_touch_and_go
iron__platform__700_65
iron__wall_bang
wood__platform__600_40
```

etc... What I want to do is pick the structure with a specific index within one theme. So not the index the set of structures of all themes together, but the index of the subset of one theme. Take a look at the piece of code again :)

---

## Update!!!

I gave wrong info. The vector is of the type `std::vector<StructureDef>`!! It stores objects. Not pointers!

So what (I think) I'm doing with the `.operator->()` call is the same as: `&(*it)`. And it looks like it is working. To me it looked a bit stupid to write & and * after each other.

---

@Ben Voigt:

Architecture:
[image]

Optimisation:
[image]

Comment: You know, your whole function appears to be `structureDefs[i].identifier == (theme + "__")`, right?

Comment: A first guess would be, that you are missing a `return` statement. This usually leads to strange return values.

Comment: @pmr, he has the return statement, take a look at the pictures. My guess is that in the line `const StructureDef *sDef= it.operator()` you are not getting the real address of the structure, but some iterator-related address. Can you work with the pointer after the function exits, or is it broken?

Comment: Probably off-topic, but using reserved names like `theme__` is a bad idea.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: I don't think that that is the problem, because the sDef pointer within the method got assigned correctly. What the `iterator.operator->()` does is simply returning the value behind the iterator.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, it can't be returning the _value_ because you assign a _pointer_ to it.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall From what I can see, he uses weird syntax to dereference the iterator (why he doesn't use (*iterator) like regular people is beyond me :L ) but it is legal syntax and shouldn't cause the pointer to spontaneously change.  If it is, wow, spooky action at a distance... FROM TEH FUTURE. Try a make clean.

Comment: @Wug, the syntax `iterator.operator->()` is kinda weird though. That `->` is confusing me... Could OP post the code of that, please?

Comment: You need to debug at the machine code (assembly language) level in order to find out exactly where and how the return value changes. I can think of 2 possibilities: (1) it doesn't, really, and (2) there is a mismatch of calling conventions involved.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall he's explicitly calling the -> operator, which takes no arguments.  It's a valid way of dereferencing an iterator (though I've never ever seen it done this way)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: the code for `operator->()` will be inside `std::vector::iterator` (or whatever container his list uses).

Comment: @Wug, ok, think I got it now...

Comment: What compiler options are you using (especially optimization)?

Comment: If you have a vector storing objects, not pointers, you should definitely not be returning pointers to those objects unless you are really, really sure there will not be any reallocations in that vector.

Comment: For all those who are suspecting the `operator->()` to be the problem, it isn't. I changed it to more clean code: `&(*it)` and I'm still having the same behavior. Which is normal, because that would explain why the return value would suddenly change...

Comment: @MadKeithV: Indeed, very fair point. But this still doesn't explain why the value before and after returning is different. Thanks for this, you are right! Do I have to fix this since the vector isn't being edited anymore at that point (i.e.: no more object pushes or pops, erases)?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux - if the vector is truly const from that point onwards then the objects will remain where they are, and the pointers will remain valid.  Even in that case though it may be a more canonical "C++-ish" approach to store iterators to the objects, not pointers.  That way everyone looking at the code will immediately wonder about iterator invalidation, and in this case that's a good thing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Can you explain what you mean by saying '*mismatch of calling conventions*'?

Comment: You're using the debug/non-optimized build right? In otimized builds gdb will get confused about what's executing and not always show the right pointers/data.

Comment: Could it be that the variable is never initialized ? Ie, does `getStructure` really returns `null` if the loop ends without anything ? It would not be the first time that I see someone being misguided by the behavior of the debugger and think that a statement is executed while it is not.

Comment: @MarkB: It is the non-optimized build (i.e.: Debug). By looking into XCode I found that the debugger was set to LLDB, and not GDB. I found this on LLDB: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9709462/155137 I'm going to debug the same with GDB.

Comment: When I use GDB, it is behaving correctly. So I guess it is a bug in LLDB. I'm going to print out the address of the pointer with a printf statement to see if LLDB is really wrong.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: a calling convention tells the compiler what the machine code expects and produces. e.g. arguments on stack or in registers, and the details of that. i don't know the calling conventions on the mac, sorry. but e.g. in Windows land there are two ways to return a result at the machine code level, namely (1) place it in memory specified by an implicitly passed pointer (used for RVO), or (2) pass it back in EAX register. if function uses different convention from caller expections, then ungood result.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense. But this is very unlikely since it is compiled by the only one compiler (i.e.: the one shipped with XCode, provided Apple, which is G++, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like the debugger I was using (LLDB and not GDB as I though first) did not display the memory values correctly. After switching to GDB, the debugger showed the memory addresses I excepted to see. When I added a print statement like this:

```
printf("StructureDef* pointer = %llx\n", (unsigned long long int)(void*) sDef);
```

it looks like GDB is right. For testing purposes, I switched back to LLDB, and magically it was working correctly as well.

Maybe, I'm dealing with what this guy wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709462/155137

I hope it is a bug in the LLDB debugger. Because, otherwise, I think there is something really broken on my installation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the vector from `std::vector<StructureDef>` to `std::vector<StructureDef*>`. When you populate the vector with its constituent pointers to `StructureDef`, dynamically allocate memory for each one on the heap.

Comment: I know, that is already discussed in the comments. Take a look at this comment and the next ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414880/c-strange-behavior-return-value-changes-on-the-return-statement/11416260#comment15054980_11414880

Comment: `boost::shared_array<StructureDef>` would be better.

Comment: No, not really, because it is like 500 lines of code, parsing an XML file with complex relation between different structs. But I can tell you that the vector is left unedited when the XML file loading is done. The `getStructure` method is called afterwars.